# Can I use GKVoiceChatService in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, ios7, gamekit, multipeer-connectivity

Even if it is depricated?

Or do I **MUST** adopt Multipeer Connectivity Framework?
Also implement my own audio streaming solution? Hope not.

---

My Voice Chat implementation just **stopped working on iOS 7**. Actually **peers just found each other**. But after I invoked a startVoiceChatWithParticipantID:, the corresponding **callback** voiceChatService:didStartWithParticipantId: **never get called**.

The same code runs lovely on iOS 6. Any similar issues? How did you get over this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Multipeer Framework then use the streaming delegate and RemoteIO or Audio Queues and their call backs in addition to a thread-safe buffer, or, as I did, install the 6.1SDK on xcode 5 and set that as your 'Base SDK'.  Hopefully, Apple will come up with MCVoiceChatService in the near future.